# Date Conversion error in Java

Tags: java, date-format

I'm trying to convert a date of type "Mon Jan 14 00:00:00 GMT-12:00 2013" to java.sql.Date yyyy/MM/dd Type , i wrote the below code . On trying to execute the below code i get "unparseable date" error .. Pls help me in solving the below problem .

```
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
     try{
               java.sql.Date xdate=new java.sql.Date(df.parse("Mon Jan 14 00:00:00 GMT-12:00 2013").getTime());
System.out.println(xdate.toString());

            }catch(Exception x)
            {
                System.out.println(x.getMessage());
            }
```

Answer (score 3):

As from the other answers, you are using the wrong pattern to parse the date string you have got.

In fact you would need that pattern, but to convert the `Date` object into the required pattern. But first you would need to get your `Date` object for the given date string. For that, you would need to build the pattern matching exactly the string you have.

There are two aspects in Date Formatting: -

- *Parsing* - Date String to Date object
- *Formatting* - Formatting Date object to Date string

So, you first need to use [`DateFormat#parse()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29), and then [`DateFormat#format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#format%28java.util.Date%29), with different patterns.

So, here's the code that you would need: -

```
String fromDate = "Mon Jan 14 00:00:00 GMT-12:00 2013";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy").parse(fromDate);

java.sql.Date toDate = new java.sql.Date(date.getTime());

System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd").format(toDate));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd")
```

so `yyyy/MM/dd` while trying to parse date in format `Mon Jan 14 00:00:00 GMT-12:00 2013`
Turn the date string you're tring to parse to `yyyy/MM/dd` form and it will be parsed.

Answer (score 1):

Well, your supplied date isn't in the format you provided. You have an ISO string as an argument, but your formatter expects "yyyy/MM/dd". Why did you expect this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need the following Simple Date format

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy");
```

**More Date and Time Patterns :** [Simple Date Format](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#Date%20and%20Time%20Patterns)

Comment: You don't need 3 z's there. Just one is needed. Replace `zzz` with `z`.

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, that I referred from java.util.Date.toString method.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyyy", Locale.US);
```

Locale.US is needed if your local language is not English and you are going to parse `Mon` and `Jan`. Date parser may be language sensitive, like in our case